# Python List - Removing all instances of a specific value

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to remove all instances of a value ("c") from a list.

```
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "c", "d"]
for i in letters:
    if i == "c":
        letters.remove(i)

print(letters)
```

The output is ["a", "b", "c", "d"] instead of the intended ["a", "b", "d"]

Why is it that only one "c" is removed, and not both/all?

Comment: Don't mutate lists that you are iterating over. Do use list comprehension e.g. `letters = [x for x in letters if x != "c"]`

Comment: `new_letters = [l for l in letters if l != 'c']`

Comment: `list(filter(lambda x: x != "c", letters))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 1):

Filter is the right approach, when you have to filter the contents of a list.

```
list(filter(lambda x: x!='c', letters))
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating a list and iterating it at the same time. When you remove the first `c` your new list will be `["a", "b", "c", "d"]` but the index is stil in the 3rd position (where was the first `c`) so it moves directly to 4th position.

If you change your list to `["a", "b", "c", "d", "c"]` you won't see the problem.

I suggest that you create a completely new list:

```
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "c", "d"]
new_letters = [i for i in letters if i != "c"]

print(new_letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not deleting/adding elements inside a loop on the list's elements.
Believe creating a new list and copying all the relevant elements to the new list will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Find `duplictaes` and then `filter`

```
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "c", "d"]


duplicates = []
for i in letters:
    count = letters.count(i)
    if count > 1 and i not in duplicates:
        duplicates.append(i)
#Filter    

print([x for x in letters if x not in duplicates])
```

output#

```
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an (admittedly ugly but working) implementation with a for loop:

```
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "c", "d"]
for i in range(len(letters)-1, -1, -1):
    if letters[i] == "c":
       del(letters[i])

print(letters)
```

Explanation: counting backwards solves the index problem mentioned by Aymen

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the duplicates using `collections.Counter`,

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: [k for k, v in Counter(letters).items() if v == 1]
Out[2]: ['a', 'b', 'd']
```